# Two MapViews in one Android Activity: jumping/flickering Markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an Android App for Tablets, which shows two maps with markers in master-detail-layout.

Both maps contain different markers. When I start to move the camera in one of the maps, markers on the other map start to jump/flicker and sometimes even stay in wrong locations.

I was able to reproduce the problem with [the google-maps android-samples](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples)
by simply adding some markers to two of the maps, nothing more. The flickering is actually far worse than visible in the gif.

[gif displaying jumping markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5z7u.gif)

Here's the whole changed Activity for completeness:

```
public class MultiMapDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final LatLng BRISBANE = new LatLng(-27.47093, 153.0235);
    private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
    private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);
    private static final LatLng ADELAIDE = new LatLng(-34.92873, 138.59995);
    private static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.952854, 115.857342);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.multimap_demo);

        final SupportMapFragment firstMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);

        firstMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                addMarkers(googleMap, multiplyMarkerPosition(BRISBANE));
                addMarkers(googleMap, multiplyMarkerPosition(MELBOURNE));
                addMarkers(googleMap, multiplyMarkerPosition(SYDNEY));
                addMarkers(googleMap, multiplyMarkerPosition(ADELAIDE));
                addMarkers(googleMap, multiplyMarkerPosition(PERTH));

                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ADELAIDE, 4f));
            }
        });

        final SupportMapFragment secondMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2);

        secondMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                addMarkersBlue(googleMap, multiplyMarkerPosition(new LatLng(51.51, 0)));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.51, 0), 4f));
            }
        });
    }

    public List<LatLng> multiplyMarkerPosition(LatLng position) {
        final LinkedList<LatLng> positions = new LinkedList<>();

        final double latitude = position.latitude;
        final double longitude = position.longitude;
        final double delta = 1;

        positions.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude + delta));
        positions.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude - delta));
        positions.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
        positions.add(new LatLng(latitude - delta, longitude + delta));
        positions.add(new LatLng(latitude - delta, longitude - delta));
        positions.add(new LatLng(latitude - delta, longitude));
        positions.add(new LatLng(latitude + delta, longitude + delta));
        positions.add(new LatLng(latitude + delta, longitude - delta));
        positions.add(new LatLng(latitude + delta, longitude));

        return positions;
    }

    public void addMarkers(GoogleMap map, List<LatLng> positions) {
        for (LatLng latLng : positions) {
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        }
    }

    public void addMarkersBlue(GoogleMap map, List<LatLng> positions) {
        for (LatLng latLng : positions) {
            map.addMarker(
                    new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't find out whether this is a known bug or an unsupported mode of operation. If you have any ideas or possible workarounds, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be a drawing bug in the Google Maps API for Android (maybe a static field in the inner implementation?). I have noticed that when the markers move you can't click on them

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll file a bug report in case this is not a known issue yet.

Comment: Please, keep this question updated. Thank you!

Comment: I just filed the bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9957. Will keep you updated.

Comment: @Jan did you ever find solution/workaround for this?

Comment: A workaround is to only show markers on one map (very limiting though)