# Google Map Composables with Markers Flickering

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-markers

I'm developing an app using Jetpack Compose and Kotlin, featuring an option to display routes in both perspective and overview modes. To achieve this, I use two Google Map composables within the app, both of which share some common markers. However, I've encountered an issue where these markers sometimes flicker.

I'm currently using the following library versions in my project:

- implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:4.3.2'
- implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose-utils:4.3.2'
- implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose-widgets:4.3.2'

After some research, I found similar issues reported by others:

- [Issue on Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828690)
- [Marker flickering in Google Map - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60074079/marker-is-flickering-in-google-map)
- [Two MapViews in one Android activity causing markers to jump/flicker - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743929/two-mapviews-in-one-android-activity-jumping-flickering-markers)

Given these references, it seems like a recurring problem with the Google Map APIs when handling multiple maps and markers. Is this flickering behavior a known bug in the Google Map APIs? Additionally, if anyone has encountered and resolved a similar issue, your insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm if you're already using the upgraded map renderer? Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer

Comment: Hi @Kat, yes, I am using the latest Maps SDK: 'implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'.

Comment: Thanks! Kindly share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community can help you better. You can also file a bug in Google's public issue tracker: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker